# Start app on android/ios remotely over wifi from a mac or pc

Tags: android, ios, iphone, wifi

our agency has an own [Open Device Lab](https://opendevicelab.com/) with me as admin :-)

We have about 50 different smart phones.
The problem is, that I have to launch the browser and choose the url out of the favorites.

Now my question is:

Is there a way to start the browser remotely via wifi (every phone is in the same wifi)

Constraint:
No phone has a installed sim card

Is there a app or something similar which can provide these feature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on Android you can use a Broadcast Receiver, so whenever it will detect WIFI, you can start a service to open browser using a particular URL or you can integrate a webview in your app to Open that custom URL.

Comment: The OP was asking about both iOS and Android. You should make it clear which one your answer refers to. (I'm an iOS developer and none of what you are saying sounds familiar, so I'm guessing that your answer is Android-specific.)

Comment: ah ok, is there maybe an app for that or do I have to write it on my own?